# If $X \sim U(-2,2)$ ,find the correlation between $X,|X|$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, covariance

If $X \sim U(-2,2)$ ,find the correlation between $X,|X|$
It is clear that $|X| \sim U(0,2)$.
Obviously , $E(X)=0$ 
Then $E(X|X|)=E(X^2 \cap X>0)-E(X^2 \cap X \le 0)=0$ due to symmetry.
Thus, the correlation coefficient becomes 0.Am I going wrong somewhere?

Comment: The correlation is indeed $0$.

Comment: Is my process correct?

Comment: It is correct. In fact $X|X|$ itself has a symmetric distribution.

Comment: $E(X\,|X|)=E(X^2\mathbf1_{X>0})-E(X^2\mathbf1_{X<0})=0$, because $X$ is symmetric about zero.

Comment: Implicitly you are saying the covariance is $E[X\,|X|] - E[X]E[|X|]$ and that both $E[X\,|X|]=0$ and $E[X]=0$, so the covariance is $0$ and thus the correlation is $0$.  It might be worth saying this explicitly